Conditional Expectation when variables are drawn from uniform distribution of different domain
I have the following problem -
$a$ and $b$ are independently drawn from uniform distribution. $a$ is drawn from uniform distribution $\{m, 1+m\}$ and $b$ is drawn from uniform distribution $\{0,1\}$. where, $0<m<1$
I have to compute expectation of a provided that $a>b$ ie. E(a|a>b) -
This will be done piecewise -
$Pr (0<b<m)\times E(a) + Pr( m<b<1)\times E(a|a>b)$
Using order statistics -
$$ m\times \frac{2m+1}{2} + (1-m) \int_{m}^{1+m} 2a^2 da $$ = $$ \frac{1}{6} (-12 m^3 + 6 m^2 + 11 m + 4)$$
Vs Expectation using old fashioned integration -
$$ m \frac{\int_0^m \int_m^{1 + m} a da db}{\int_0^m \int_m^{1 + m} 1da db} + (1 - m) \frac{ \int_m^1 \int_b^{1 + m} a da db} { \int_m^1 \int_b^{1 + m} 1da db} = \frac{2 m^3 + 3 m^2 + 9 m + 4}{6 m + 6} $$
Both behave same at end points, m=0 and m=1. But expectation rises more quickly when calculated using order statistics than the integration way.
Which one is correct? Why are they different? Is there a problem with calculation?

I have already mentioned that I am trying to calculate conditional expected value of a >b

It should be 2/3. Even when m=0, a is higher order statistic.

All things reconsidered, I take back all the words that I said and am about to introduce the solution which works fine and satisfies Python simulations I've run.
To calculate the conditional expectation, proceed as follows:
$$
\mathbb{E}[a\, | a>b] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[a\cdot{\mathbf{1}_{[a>b]}}]}{\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{[a>b]}]}
$$
To calculate the denominator, it suffices to calculate the following integral:
$$
\int_{m}^{m+1} da \int_{0}^{\min{[a; 1]}} db = 
\int_{m}^{m+1} {\min{[a; 1]}} \, da =  
\int_{m}^{1} {a} \, da + \int_{1}^{m+1} \, da=  \frac{1}{2}(1+2m-m^2).
$$
To calculate the numerator, we should calculate a similar integral, including expectation over $a$:
$$
\int_{m}^{m+1} a\, da \int_{0}^{\min{[a; 1]}} db = 
\int_{m}^{m+1} a\cdot{\min{[a; 1]}} \, da =  
\int_{m}^{1} {a}^{2} \, da + \int_{1}^{m+1} a \, da = \\
\frac{a^3}{3}\bigg|_{m}^{1} + \frac{a^2}{2}\bigg|_{1}^{m+1} = 
\frac{1}{3}(1-m^{3}) + \frac{1}{2}((m+1)^2-1)
$$
That finally yields:
$$
\mathbb{E}[a\, | a>b] = \frac{\frac{1}{3}(1-m^{3}) + \frac{1}{2}((m+1)^2-1)}{\frac{1}{2}(1+2m-m^2)}
$$

for $m=0$ it gives $\mathbb{E}[a\, | a>b] = \frac{2}{3}$
for $m=1$ it gives $\mathbb{E}[a\, | a>b] = \frac{3}{2}$

Python code to prove the solution is correct.
import scipy.stats as st
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ms = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
trials = 10000
results = []
expectation = lambda m: (1/3*(1-m**3) + 1/2*((m+1)**2 - 1))/(1/2*(1+2*m-m**2))

for m in ms:
    a = st.uniform(m, 1)
    b = st.uniform()
    as_ = a.rvs(size=trials)
    bs_ = b.rvs(size=trials)
    exp = np.sum( (as_ > bs_) * as_ ) / np.sum( (as_ > bs_) )
    results.append(exp)

plt.plot(ms, expectation(ms), label='Theoretical expectation', color='grey', ls=':')
plt.plot(ms, results, label='Experimental expectation', color='green', alpha=.3)
plt.grid(ls=':', alpha=.4); plt.xlabel('$m$'); plt.ylabel('$E[a | a > b]$')
plt.legend()


Equivalently, you could integrate in a different order, namely:
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}{[a>b]}] = \int{0}^{1} db \int_{\max{[b, m]}}^{m+1} da
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{E}[a\cdot\mathbf{1}{[a>b]}] = \int{0}^{1} db \int_{\max{[b, m]}}^{m+1} a da
$$

Thank you! I understand that I didn't need to consider the probabilities. Yours is much clearer and better!
